Invariant subspaces and primary decomposion
I was given the following problem :
we are given $T : V \rightarrow V$ linear operator which has $2$ eigenvalues $x_1, x_2$.
let $U$ be a $T$-invariant subspace in $V$. let $V= V_1 \oplus V_2$ be the primary decompostion with respect to $T$ and it's 2 eigenvalues.
prove that $U = (U \cap V_1) \oplus (U \cap V_2)$
I was only able to prove that the sum is indeed direct, but i can't quite get how to show that if $u \in U$ then $u \in (U \cap V_1) \oplus (U \cap V_2)$. the other way around is trivial ofcourse.
any help would be much appricated.

Is the linear map $T\colon V \to V$ supposed to be diagonalisable, or do you simply mean that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(t-x_1)^a(t-x_2)^b$ for some exponents $a,b$ with $a+b=n=\dim(V)$? Assuming you mean the latter, consider how the existence of the primary decomposition is established for $T\colon V \to V$ but also for $T \colon U \to U$.

can you elaborate please? i dont quite understand your point

@JohannCarlFriedrichGauß km2233 is asking if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the $x_1$-eigenspace and $x_2$-eigenspace. For example, if $T$ has the matrix representation $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ w.r.t. some basis, then $1$ is the eigenvalue but it only has one eigenvector and so the eigenspace is not the whole vector space.

If the minimal polynomial for $T\colon V \to V$ is $(t-x_1)^a(t-x_2)^b$ where $a+b=k \leq n =\dim(V)$ then the primary decomposition for $V$ shows that $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ is a direct sum of invariant subspaces where $T_{|V_1}$ has minimal polynomial $(t-x_1)^a$ and $T_{|V_2}$ has minimal polynomial $(t-x_2)^b$.
One way to establish this is to use "Bezout's Lemma": since $(t-x_1)^a$ and $(t-x_2)^b$ are coprime, there exist polynomials $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ such that
$$
r(t)(t-x_1)^a + s(t)(t-x_2)^b = 1.
$$
Thus evaluating this at $t=T$ we find that
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
1_V = r(T)(T-x_11_V)^a + s(t)(T-x_21_V)^b
$$
so that if $v \in V$ then $v = r(T)(T-x_11_V)^a(v) + s(T)(T-x_21_V)^b(v)$, and one can define $V_1 = r(T)(T-x_11_V)^a(V)$ and $V_2 = s(T)(T-x_2 1_V)^b(V)$. It is easy to see that $(T-x_21_V)^b$ acts as zero on the $V_1$ and similarly $(T-x_11_V)^a$ acts by zero on $s(T)(T-x_21_V)^b(V)$, and with a bit more thought you can see that these are the minimal polynomials for the action $T$.
Now suppose that $U$ is a $T$-stable subspace. Applying $(\dagger)$ to any vector $u \in U$ shows that $u = u_1 + u_2$ where $u_1 \in U \cap V_1$ and $u_2 \in U \cap V_2$.
